An epoll is listening data from multiple fds , how to give priority to a specific fd
n = epoll_wait(epfd, events, MAXEVENTS, -1);
        std::vector<int32_t> lowPriorFDs , highPriorFDs;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if((events[i].events & EPOLLERR) || (events[i].events & EPOLLHUP) || (!(events[i].events & EPOLLIN)))
            {
                /*An error has occured on this fd, or the socket is not
                 ready for reading (why were we notified then?) */
                 fprintf (stderr, "epoll error\n");
                  continue;
                  //exit(-1);
            }else{
                  int fd = events[i].data.fd;
                  if(_omsFd == fd){
                    highPriorFDs.push_back(fd);
                  }else{
                    lowPriorFDs.push_back(fd);
                  }
            }
        }
            //Here we are keeping the high priority FDs first , here we are giving the priority to the Strategies messg.    
            std::vector<int> FDs;
            FDs.reserve( highPriorFDs.size() + lowPriorFDs.size() ); // preallocate memory
            FDs.insert( FDs.end(), highPriorFDs.begin(), highPriorFDs.end() );
            FDs.insert( FDs.end(), lowPriorFDs.begin(), lowPriorFDs.end() );

for(int32_t fd : FDs){
   if(fd == CHECK_FD){
}
}



Requirement:
whenever data came to high priority fds , stop low priority fds and give priority to high prioritt FD.
so would the above mine solution will work for this , or there is any efficient way for the above.

You probaby missed the If more than maxevents file descriptors are ready when epoll_wait() is called, then successive poll_wait() calls will round robin through the set of ready file descriptors. in the manpage... so I'm guessing your ordering doesn't help you.

AFAIK there's no way to tell epoll that some file descriptors have higher priority than others.

@JesperJuhl  what could be the best possible for above problem , listen the data of high priority fd in other epoll ?

@ChristianStieber
